# Can't sync nor delete photos to manage storage

Tags: iphone, storage

In My usage -> Storage -> Photos it says that 7.4 GB are used and that I have over 2000 pictures. But I only have 150 photos on my phone. iTunes will not sync because I have no room. What can I do?